# When I close the modal all the hidden.bs.close are trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have 3 divs,
this one will be the modal

id="myModal"

the other divs will be the content of modal - new and edit operations so:

id="new" data-view='New-Operation'

id="edit" data-view='Edit-Operation'

```
function init(){      
     var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
                modal.innerHTML = "";
                modal.innerHTML = $("#new");
}

$("#myModal").on("[data-view='New-Operation'] hidden.bs.modal", function () {
});

$("#myModal").on("[data-view='Edit-Operation'] hidden.bs.modal", function () {
})



init();
```

why both of them are trigger?

Comment: can you share how you are closing the modal ?

Comment: close button and click outside the modal

Answer (score 1):

> hidden.bs.modal is the **Event** type that will be triggered

Try changing this :

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
modal.innerHTML = "";
$("#myModal").attr('data-view','New-Operation');
modal.innerHTML = $("#new");


$("#myModal div[data-view='New-Operation']").on(" hidden.bs.modal", function () {

});

$("#myModal div[data-view='Edit-Operation']").on(" hidden.bs.modal", function () {

});
```

Comment: its not working because the code :
$("#myModal div[data-view='New-Operation']").on(" hidden.bs.modal", function () {

});

run before the div has this data-view...so no binding here

Answer (score 0):

hidden.bs.modal event are triggered when any modal on the page be hidden, So you don't need to create two modals, you should create only one modal and change the body of it according to your operation.

another solution that allows you to keep using two modals that you get rid of hidden.bs.modal event and declare 2 js functions HideModal1(), and HideModal2(), and call them in the dismiss-button of modal, but notice that you should remove data-dismiss="modal" attribute from the button and replace it with onclick attribute

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="HideModal1()">Close</button>
```

Hope that helps!